# C Reverse Queue

Tags: c, data-structures, queue

How do I reverse a queue using dequeue and enqueue functions?

Is it a must to use 2 queue to reverse the queue?

This is my code:

```
void reverse(Queue *q)
{
    Queue *new_q = (Queue*) malloc(sizeof(Queue));
    new_q->ll.head = NULL;
    new_q->ll.size = 0;

    ListNode *pLast;

    while(!isEmptyQueue(q)){
        pLast = q->ll.tail;
        while(q->ll.head != pLast){
            dequeue(q);
            enqueue(q, q->ll.head->item);
        }
        dequeue(q);
        enqueue(new_q, q->ll.head->item);
    }

    while(!isEmptyQueue(new_q))
    {
        dequeue(new_q);
        enqueue(q, q->ll.head->item);
    }
    free(new_q);
}
```

Comment: recursion is your friend.

Comment: You could use a `stack` to reverse a `queue`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it as below using recursion:

```
void reverse(Queue *queue) {
    int element;
    if (isEmptyQueue(queue)) {
      return;
    }
    element = dequeue(queue);
    reverse(queue);
    enqueue(queue, element);
}
```

Internally it would store element in function stack and once your queue is emptied out, it would start populating queue again from last element till the first. This method implicitly uses stack, you could do the same using Stack data structure explicitly.

Comment: You are using the stack here by using the recusrsion. So it is basically same solution as I desrcribed

Comment: what is this `private` keyword?

Comment: @ChristianGibbons was a typo. Thanks :) coderredoc see my comment below the question.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to use stack to reverse the queue. You know how to do that. Just dequeue the queue (empty the queue) and then pop from the stack and enqueue in the queue. You end up with the reversed queue now.

To realize a stack you need 2 queue, that's why 2 queue is needed.

You can do this in one queue also:-(you can implemet stack using one queue also)

```
// E is the element to be pushed and s is stack
push(s, E) 
  1) Let size of queue be sz. 
  1) Enqueue E to queue
  2) One by one Dequeue sz items from queue and enqueue them.

// Removes an item from stack
pop(s)
  1) Dequeue an item from queue
```